# Поиск строки по вложенным массивам

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Всем привет.
Есть задача с помощью рекурсии пройти по объекту и посчитать сколько в нем строк.
Рекурсию нужна если есть вложенный массив.
Пример объекта:

```
const obj = {
first: "1",
second: "2",
third: false,
fourth: ["anytime", 2, 3, 4],
fifth: null,
};
```

Функция:

```
function getStringCount(object) {
  const arr = Object.values(object);
  let count = arr.reduce((count, item) => {
    if (typeof item === "string") {
      count++;
    } else if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      getStringCount(item);
    }
    return count;
  }, 0);
  
  return count
}
```

Я пробую это сделать с помощью reduce и без глобальной переменной. Я пробовал отследить возвращаемые значения с помощью console.log. В консоле выводится два значения 1 - результат проверки вложенного массива и 2 - результат проверки внешнего массива. Если сделать return то конечным значением будет 2. Вопрос такой, как мне сложить два результата, что бы ф-я возвращала 3?

Comment: Почему вы игнорируете возвращаемое значение в `getStringCount(item);` ?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо, ваш комментарий очень помог!

Answer (score 0):

Комментарию от Stanislav Volodarskiy:

> Почему вы игнорируете возвращаемое значение в getStringCount(item); ?

Навел меня на мысль и я привел код к такому виду и все заработало:

```
function getStringCount(object) {
  const arr = Object.values(object);
  let count = arr.reduce((count, item) => {
    let i = 0;
    if (typeof item === "string") {
      count++;
    } else if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        i = getStringCount(item);
    }
    return count + i;
  }, 0);
  return count
}
```